# Dynamic content with Jekyll

Tags: php, dynamic, blogs, jekyll

I am thinking of using Jekyll as the blogging engine for an upcoming project. However, I need a small part of the website to be dynamic, using some sort of sever-side language (Ruby, PHP, Node.js, etc.)

I want the posts to be static as you would expect from Jekyll, however at the bottom of the page I have a piece of content that needs to rotate randomly on each page load. I don't want to use JavaScript to do this.

Is this possible within Jekyll?

Comment: Why don't you want to use javascript?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [server side includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes). You might need to configure the server or change the extension of the generated files to .shtml.

Jekyll should generate this where you need to insert dynamic content:

```
<!--#include virtual="dynamic.rb" -->
```

dynamic.rb should produce valid html to display.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use javascript at all, you can put the dynamic content on a different server and then embed it in your jekyll site using an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

No, Jekyll only creates static pages. You'll have to use JavaScript for any dynamic content.